# Form action not working in php?

Tags: php, forms, action

I have basically 2 forms in one page.
First one is for login and second one is for insert data.
Second form action is working fine. i can insert data with it.
But same form I'm using for login user but it's not working.
On click submit button nothing happens just page refresh.

please see my code and help me to solve my first form's action issue.

```
<div class="login_wrapper">
  <div id="login" class="animate form login_form">
    <section class="login_content">
      <form action="login.php" method="post">
        <h1>Login Form</h1>
        <div>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required=""  name="username" />
        </div>
        <div>
          <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required="" name="password" />
        </div>
        <div>
          <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="insert" value="Sign In">
          <a class="reset_pass" href="#forgetpass">Lost your password?</a>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <div class="separator">
          <p class="change_link">New to site?
            <a href="#signup" class="to_register"> Create Account </a>
          </p>

          <div class="clearfix"></div>
          <br />

          <div>
            <h1><i class="fa fa-paw"></i> DiGItal Society</h1>
            <p>©2016 All Rights Reserved. DiGItal Society is a Web Portal for E-Society. Privacy and Terms</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>            
    </section>
  </div>

  <div id="register" class="animate form registration_form">
    <section class="login_content">
      <form action="insertUser.php" method="post">
        <h1>Create Account</h1>
        <div>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required="" name="username" />
        </div>
        <div>
          <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" required="" name="email" />
        </div>
        <div>
          <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required="" name="password" />
        </div>
        <div>
          <input type="hidden" name="roleid" value="">
          <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="insert" value="Log In">
        </div>

        <div class="clearfix"></div>

        <div class="separator">
          <p class="change_link">Already a member ?
            <a href="#signin" class="to_register"> Log in </a>
          </p>

          <div class="clearfix"></div>
          <br />

          <div>
            <h1><i class="fa fa-paw"></i> DiGItal Society</h1>
            <p>©2016 All Rights Reserved. DiGItal Society is a Web Portal for E-Society. Privacy and Terms</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have also add my action pages.(not working).
`login.php` for first form(not working)

```
<?php
include 'db.php';
if (isset($_REQUEST['insert'])) 
    {
    echo    $username = $_REQUEST['username'];

    echo    $password = $_REQUEST['password'];
        $sql = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM `accountants` where `acc_email` = '$username' AND `acc_pass` = '$password'");
        $data = mysqli_fetch_array($conn,$sql);
        $_SESSION['role']=$data['roleId'];
        $_SESSION['username']=$data['acc_name'];
        $data = mysqli_num_rows($data);
        if ($data>0) 
            {
                header('Location: home.php');
            }
        else
            {
                header('Location: index.php');
                echo 'incorrect login';
            }
    }
?>
```

and `insertUser.php` for second form.(working)

```
<?php
include 'db.php';
if (isset($_REQUEST['insert'])) 
    {
        $acc_name = $_REQUEST['username'];
        $acc_email = $_REQUEST['email'];
        $acc_pass = $_REQUEST['password'];
        $role_id = $_REQUEST['roleid'];
        $sql = mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO `accountants`(`acc_name`, `acc_email`, `acc_pass`, `roleId`) VALUES ('".$acc_name."','".$acc_email."','".$acc_pass."','2')");
        if ($sql>0) 
            {
                header('Location: home.php');
                echo 'data added successfully';
            }
        $row = mysqli_query('SELECT * FROM `accountants`');     
        $data = mysqli_fetch_array($row);
        $data = mysqli_num_rows($conn,$data);
        $_SESSION['role'] = $data['roleId'];
    }
?>
```

Comment: Try with a different `name` in input submit for the first form. And use it in the login.php

Comment: @KinshukLahiri ok i try it but not working . still on same page

Comment: What it the output for this `print_r($_REQUEST); print_r($_POST["insert"])`; die;` for the login.php file.

Comment: @KinshukLahiri i got `Array ( [user] => a [pass] => a [login] => Sign In )` this on request . but what's the problem if i used request and die then only i can see this result, if i used only `print_r` without `die` then nothing happens on page

Comment: @amitsutar is this a live or going live site?

Comment: yup bro its going to live @Fred-ii-

Comment: @amitsutar If you're using that exact code; don't, because you will get hacked. Use a prepared statement and `password_hash()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php then `password_verify()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php for the login.

Comment: @Fred-ii- thanks bro sure i will use it

Comment: @amitsutar you're welcome; *stay safe* ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution: Try this:

Inside the if condition:

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['insert']))
```

Change the above to this:

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['login']))
```

PS: Change these as well:

```
 echo    $username = $_REQUEST['username'];

 echo    $password = $_REQUEST['password'];
```

to:

```
echo    $username = $_REQUEST['user'];

echo    $password = $_REQUEST['pass'];
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: still not working bro. i tried this earlier . dont know whts the issue

Comment: @amitsutar Updated.

Comment: @amitsutar `Array ( [user] => a [pass] => a [login] => Sign In )` is the output. I hope this is for `print_r($_REQUEST); and is placed in the login.php file.`

Comment: @amitsutar Then its not possible. Cause the key name was wrong earlier and now its correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try to rename `name="insert"` in `<input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="insert" value="Sign In">` from form login.
because name is same.

For example `<input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="login" value="Sign In">`

and don't forget rename login.php

```
<?php
include 'db.php';
if (isset($_REQUEST['login'])) 
    {
    echo    $username = $_REQUEST['username'];

    echo    $password = $_REQUEST['password'];
        $sql = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM `accountants` where `acc_email` = '$username' AND `acc_pass` = '$password'");
        $data = mysqli_fetch_array($conn,$sql);
        $_SESSION['role']=$data['roleId'];
        $_SESSION['username']=$data['acc_name'];
        $data = mysqli_num_rows($data);
        if ($data>0) 
            {
                header('Location: home.php');
            }
        else
            {
                header('Location: index.php');
                echo 'incorrect login';
            }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution fix your login.php page.

```
    <?php

if (isset($_POST['insert'])) 
    {
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        $sql = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM `accountants` where `acc_email` = '$username' AND `acc_pass` = '$password'");
        $data = mysqli_fetch_array($conn,$sql);
        $_SESSION['role']=$data['roleId'];
        $_SESSION['username']=$data['acc_name'];
        $data = mysqli_num_rows($data);
        if ($data>0) 
            {
                header('Location: home.php');
            }
        else
            {
                header('Location: index.php');
                echo 'incorrect login';
            }
    }
?>
```

Comment: what errors are you receiving? Still page is reloading ?

Comment: not getting any errors just page reloading onclick that's it, nothing happens.

Comment: I have edited the code of login.php and now it is working try this